# How Anti-forgery key validate on cross domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I have 2 project(s).

```
1.[MVC.Presentation] (https://localhost:44304)
      |__Login.cshtml
            |__AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken)
```

`GetTokens` Function is used to generate anti-forgery token. This process is not depanded on any other projects because it can generate anti-foregery token when other services are shutting down.

```
2.[WebApi.TokenService] (https://localhost:44305)
      |__ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute
             |___AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
```

`WebApi.TokenService` validate anti-forgery token key whenever it received request(s).
Both projects are working well.

But my question is,

How `WebApi.TokenService` project know the corrected anti-forgery token since anti-forgery token is generated by other project named `MVC.Presentation`?

To be more detailed, both project are running seperately on different domains.

When I tested using fake token, `Antiforgery.Validate` function really know that my token is not corrected.

So how could they know each other ?

Is this because of [Machine key](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2014/01/29/htmlantiforgerytoken-ndash-balancing-security-with-usability) ?

Comment: Good question, I have the same one. Did you find the answer?

Comment: after 2 years, there is still no answer for this? frankly i need an explanation to implement anti-forgery for both angularjs+asp.net mvc and web api